# Nothing is happening when I click the delete button reactjs

Tags: reactjs

So this is my index.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import './index.css';

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have created 2 source files table.js and application.js

This is my table.js(here I pass the method removeCharacter):

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Table extends Component{

      render() {
        const { characterData, removeCharacter } = this.props;
        return(
          <table>
            <TableHeader />
            <TableBody 
              characterData={characterData}
              removeCharacter={removeCharacter} 
            />
          </table>
        );
      }
    }

    const TableHeader = () => {
      return (
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Job</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      )
    }

    const TableBody = props => {
      const rows = props.characterData.map((row, index) =>{
        return (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{row.name}</td>
            <td>{row.job}</td>
            <td><button onClick={() => props.removeCharacter(index)}>Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
        );
      });

      return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    }
   export default Table;
```

On my App.js, I'm trying to implement States to add a delete method removeCharacter. As what the tutorial that I'm following says, I just need to move all the array objects into this 'state' block.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Table from './Table';

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        characters: [
          {
            'name': 'Charlie',
            'job': 'Janitor'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Mac',
            'job': 'Bouncer'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Dee',
            'job': 'Aspiring actress'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Dennis',
            'job': 'Bartender'
          }
        ]
      };

      removeCharacter = index => {
        const { characters } = this.state;

        this.setState({
          characters: characters.filter((character, i) => {
            return i !== index;
          })
        });
      }
      render()  {
        const characters = [
          {
            'name': 'Charlie',
            'job': 'Janitor'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Mac',
            'job': 'Bouncer'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Dee',
            'job': 'Aspiring actress'
          },
          {
            'name': 'Dennis',
            'job': 'Bartender'
          },
        ];
        return(
          <div className="container">
            <Table 
              characterData={characters}
              removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} 
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

When I click my the delete button, nothing is happening.

Comment: delete characters inside render method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App.js render method, the characters constant should be referring to the state like so, because the removeCharacter method is changing the state whereas the characters variable within the render method is statically defined.

```
render()  {
    const { characters } = this.state;

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Table 
          characterData={characters}
          removeCharacter={this.removeCharacter} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can understand, I was confused.